# How to get the logical right binary shift in python

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

As revealed by the title, in JavaScript there is a specific operator `>>>`. For example, in JavaScript we will have the following result:

```
(-1000) >>> 3 = 536870787

(-1000) >> 3 = -125

1000 >>> 3 = 125

1000 >> 3 = 125
```

So is there a certain method or operator representing this `>>>`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There isn't a built-in operator for this, but you can easily simulate the `>>>` yourself:

```
>>> def rshift(val, n): return val>>n if val >= 0 else (val+0x100000000)>>n
... 
>>> rshift(-1000, 3)
536870787
>>> rshift(1000, 3)
125
```

The following alternative implementation removes the need for the `if`:

```
>>> def rshift(val, n): return (val % 0x100000000) >> n
```

Comment: `(val + 0x100000000) % 0x100000000)` is `val % 0x100000000`.

Comment: @Baffe Boyois: in Python it most certainly isn't (the result is always positive whereas the first operand can have either sign).

Comment: Example? Note that `-1 % 3 == 2` in Python. ["The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero)"](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

Comment: 0x100000000 is `1 << 32`, and 32 is the number of bits used to represent the integer (which is important but not stated anywhere). If you had 64 bit integers then you'd have to use `1 << 64` instead.

Comment: This answer is WRONG if val < 0 and n == 0 !!  See a corrected answer below.  rshift(-1, 0) = 4294967295 with this answer!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64987033/839733) explains the logic behind `val+0x100000000`.

Comment: @systemBuilder This how logical/unsigned right shift behaves in other languages. If you do `val >>> 0` it essentially converts it to unsigned. Open your browser console and try for yourself.

Answer (score 11):

No, there isn't. The right shift in python is arithmetical.

Comment: So is this included in some package anyway?

Comment: Since Python doesn't have unsigned numbers, it only makes sense that it wouldn't include unsigned shifts.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: That's wrong, you might need to compute an expression defined in another language (just as I do now). But I agree that due to the non-existence of unsigned numbers the need for unsigned shift is rather limited.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a spinoff of [aix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5833119/5987). The normal right-shift operator will work if you feed it a positive value, so you're really looking for a conversion from signed to unsigned.

```
def unsigned32(signed):
    return signed % 0x100000000

>>> unsigned32(-1000) >> 3
536870787L
```

Answer (score 2):

[Numpy](https://numpy.org/) provides the [`right_shift()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.right_shift.html#numpy.right_shift) function that does this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.right_shift(1000, 3)
125
```

Comment: But isn't that just the `>>` operator? If I try `numpy.right_shift(-1000, 3)` I get `-125` not `536870787`.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths is right. However you can use numpy to convert to an unsigned type, and then the normal operator works, e.g: `numpy.uint32(-1000) >> 3`. Be aware that the output type when I tested this specific case was `numpy.int64` (signed).

Answer (score 2):

You can do a bitwise shift padding with zeros with the [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) module using the [>>=](https://web.archive.org/web/20120721013854/http://packages.python.org:80/bitstring/bitarray.html#bitstring.BitArray.__irshift__) operator:

```
>>> a = BitArray(int=-1000, length=32)
>>> a.int
-1000
>>> a >>= 3
>>> a.int
536870787
```

Comment: Rotate is not the same as shift.

Comment: @Mark: Fair point - I had misunderstood what the >>> operator was doing. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to flip the sign bit of a negative number by masking it with  0x100000000 is fundamentally misconceived as it makes hard assumptions about the word length. In my time as a programmer I have worked with 24-, 48-, 16-, 18-, 32-, 36- and 64-bit numbers. I have also heard of machines that work on odd-lengths, such as 37 and others that use ones-complement, and not twos-complement, arithmetic. Any assumptions you make about the internal representation of numbers, beyond that they are binary, is dangerous.

Even the binary assumption is not absolutely safe, but I think we'll allow that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that if the number is negative, the top bit is set and with each shift right you need to make the top bit set as well.

Here is my implementation:

```
def rshift(val, n):
    s = val & 0x80000000
    for i in range(0,n):
        val >>= 1
        val |= s
    return val
```

Comment: I think you got the sense of the question backwards.  All python shifts are arithmetic.  You have implemented an arithmetic shift., duplicating python's functionality  The original question is asking for a logical shift operator, not an arithmetic shift.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works without a modulo:

`>>> def rshift(val,n): return (val>>n) & (0x7fffffff>>(n-1))`

This works since 7fffffff is a positive number and right shifting that will add zeros to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use floor division:

```
def rshift(val, n):
    if val > 0:
        return val >> n
    return val // -(2^n)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not an efficient approach but works just as expected

```
def _toBinary(x):
    x=int(x)
    binary = []
    while x > 0:
        binary.append(str(x%2))
        x=int(x/2)
    return "".join(binary[::-1])

def _fromBinary(xs):
    ans = 0
    for i,x in enumerate(xs[::-1]):
        if x == '1':
            ans += 2**i
    return ans

def leftLogicalShift(x,n=1):
    if not type(x) == int:
        return x
    xs = _toBinary(x)
    xs = [x for x in xs]
    for _ in range(n):
        xs.pop(0)
        xs.append('0')
    return _fromBinary("".join(xs))

def rightLogicalShift(x,n=1):
    if not type(x) == int:
        return x
    xs = _toBinary(x)
    xs = [x for x in xs]
    for _ in range(n):
        xs.pop()
        xs.insert(0,'0')
    return _fromBinary("".join(xs))

def leftArithmeticShift(x,n=1):
    return leftLogicalShift(x,n)

def rightArithmeticShift(x,n=1):
    if not type(x) == int:
        return x
    xs = _toBinary(x)
    xs = [x for x in xs]
    for _ in range(n):
        tmp = xs[0]
        xs.pop()
        xs.insert(0,tmp)
    return _fromBinary("".join(xs))

lls = leftLogicalShift(10,2) 
print(lls) # 8

rls = rightLogicalShift(10,2) 
print(rls) # 2

las = leftArithmeticShift(10,2)
print(las) # 8

ras = rightArithmeticShift(10,2)
print(ras) # 14
```

references:

https://open4tech.com/logical-vs-arithmetic-shift/

https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/bit-shift

Answer (score -2):

The top-voted answer (66 votes) produces WRONG results for val < 0 and n == 0!  Here is a correct function - it produces correct values for 32-bit arithmetic and right shift of -1 by 0, 1, 2, 3.

```
def rshift(val, n):
    if (val >= 0): return val >> n
    elif (n == 0): return val
    else: return (val + 0x100000000) >> n

>>> rshift(-1, 0)
-1
```

Answer (score -3):

I think a *logical right binary shift* is not available in Python directly. Instead you can use Javascript in Python as in:

```
import js2py
rshift = js2py.eval_js('function $(a, b){ return a >>> b}')
print (rshift(244, 324)) #15
```