# Python Unsigned Right Shift

Tags: python, operators, bit-manipulation, shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the logical right binary shift in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832982/how-to-get-the-logical-right-binary-shift-in-python)

How do I perform an unsigned right shift in python?

I.E. The java equivalent is this:

```
x >>> y or x >>>= y
```

Answer (score 22):

Integers in Java have a fixed number of bits, but those in Python don't, so an unsigned right shift would be meaningless in Python.