# Zero fill right shift in python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, bit-shift

```
function(e, t) {
    return e << t | e >>> 32 - t
}
```

I have this method in js, I do not understand in deep about shift operation. I want to write that in python. How can I write the equivalent code in python as it does not support **Zero Fill Right Shift Operator as in JS** `>>>`.

Comment: does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to get the logical right binary shift in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832982/how-to-get-the-logical-right-binary-shift-in-python)  An elegant solution is: `def rshift(val, n): return (val % 0x100000000) >> n`. See that question and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a built-in zero fill right shift operator in Python, but you can easily define your own `zero_fill_right_shift` function:

```
def zero_fill_right_shift(val, n):
    return (val >> n) if val >= 0 else ((val + 0x100000000) >> n)
```

Then you can define your function:

```
def f(e, t):
    return e << t or zero_fill_right_shift(e, 32 - t)
```